# Getting Error while converting numpy.array into list and trying to find Index

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code,

```
l1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

suppose, If I want to find the Index of an Item, I can easily find it like this

```
l1.index([7,8,9])
--output 
2

type(l1)
--output
list
```

But, When I try to convert the list into Numpy.array and then convert it back to list and then if I try to find the index of an element, I am getting an error

```
l1=list(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))

l1.index([7,8,9])
```

[image]

Why am I getting this error and how to resolve this?

Comment: look at `l1`.  It is a list, but is it the list of lists that you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `tolist()` function in order to get the proper conversion from `np.array` to Python built-in `list`:

```
import numpy as np

l1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print(l1.index([7,8,9]))

l1=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).tolist()

print(l1.index([7,8,9]))
```

**Output:**

```
2
2
```

Comment: but when i print the type it is showing as list, if that is the case then why am i not able to acces the properties of python list, could you explain me on this

Comment: @lijin-durairaj You're right, both objects are of type `list`. The thing is that `list()` is a built-in Python implementation that converts objects to lists. But `tolist()` is an specific function made by NumPy developers that convert an `np.array` object to a Python list.

Comment: @lijin-durairaj That means, sometimes `list()` method can fail at the conversion, meanwhile `tolist()` is assured not to fail because it only converts from one type of object. Please take a look at both Python and Numpy documentation to learn more about both functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: l1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

In [5]: arr = np.array(l1)

In [6]: arr
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

`tolist` performs a thorough conversion to python base structures - not just lists, but also the numeric elements.

```
In [7]: arr.tolist()
Out[7]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

`list` just converts the first dimension:

```
In [8]: list(arr)
Out[8]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

It's equivalent to this list comprehension:

```
In [9]: [a for a in arr]
Out[9]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
```

`tolist` is also faster.

As for your error

```
In [10]: list(arr).index([7,8,9])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 list(arr).index([7,8,9])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

you have to understand how `index` works, and how `==` works for arrays.

`index` iterates through the elements of the list and applies an equality test, first with `id` and then with `==`.

for the list of lists:

```
In [14]: [sublist==[7,8,9] for sublist in l1]
Out[14]: [False, False, True]
```

but for the list of arrays:

```
In [15]: [sublist==[7,8,9] for sublist in list(arr)]
Out[15]: 
[array([False, False, False]),
 array([False, False, False]),
 array([ True,  True,  True])]
```

For lists `==` tests the whole lists, and returns a simple True/False.  For arrays, the result is an element-wise test, producing multiple True/False.  That's what the "ambiguity" error is all about.